# How to setup prop type when passing in different props to a re-usable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react-typescript question. So I want to pass down different props to a reusable component from 2 different parent components.

```
import React from 'react'

const ComponentA = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentC propA={someprops} propB={someprops} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentA
```

```
import React from 'react'

const ComponentB = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentC propC={someprops} propD={someprops} /> // different 
                                                                  props
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentB
```

How do I setup the prop types in componentC to take in those different prop types?

```
import React from 'react'

const ComponentC = ({props}: // how to annotate type?) => {
    return (
        <div>
            somecode
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Each parent component would render their own instance of `<ComponentC>` with the unique props that you passed to them. Where are you having an issue?

Comment: If `ComponentC` can have any props, `props: any` might be an option. I think the problem is insufficiently described to offer a better suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `ComponentC` can accept two different sets of props. I would probably define each combination and then say the props can be of one combination or the other. For example:

```
type OptionOneProps = {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}

type OptionTwoProps = {
  propC: string;
  propD: string;
}

const ComponentC = (props: OptionOneProps | Option2Props) => {

  ...

}
```